# Get access_token with fetch() for Login with GitHub

Tags: github, fetch

I'm writing SSO with GitHub and cannot extract access_token after using fetch() function

```
const url = `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=${process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${process.env.GITHUB_REDIRECT_URI}&client_secret=${process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}&code=${code}`;
    
    fetch(url, {method: 'POST'}).then(result => result.text())  
    .then(text => {
        console.log('text', text)
        access_token = JSON.parse(text)['access_token'] 
    })
```

the output is

```
text access_token=fe07bb27637ac176058f2&scope=user%3Aemail&token_type=bearer
```

Which is file! But the next step - to get access_token is failed with:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I rewrote this part with superagent and it works perfectly. But still want to make this possible with fetch()

```
superagent
.post('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token')
.send({ 
    client_id: `${process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}`,
    redirect_uri: `${process.env.GITHUB_REDIRECT_URI}`,
    client_secret: `${process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`,
    code: `${code}`
 }) // sends a JSON post body
.set ('Accept', 'application/json')
.end((err, result) => {
    const token = result.body.access_token
```

Hope you can help me to find why my fetch() is not working...